# SwiftUI- Timer auto adds 30 minutes to countdown

Tags: swift, swiftui, timer

I'm trying to make a timer in swiftui but whenever I run it, it auto adds 30 minutes to the countdown. For example, when I set the countdown time to 5 minutes and click the "Start" button, it will show up as 35 minutes instead but when I click the button again, it will then just keep switching to random times. Above is the random times it will switch to.[image]

I got this timer from a tutorial on youtube by Indently but changed some things to fit what I wanted it to do. I tried to set a custom time so the timer will always countdown from 5 minutes. From my understanding, the timer works by taking the difference between the current date and the end date then using the amount of time difference as the countdown. Below is the code for the TimerStruct (ViewModel) and the TimerView.

TimerStruct:

```
import Foundation

extension TimerView {
    final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var isActive = false
        @Published var showingAlert = false
        @Published var time: String = "5:00"
        @Published var minutes: Float = 5.0 {
            didSet {
                self.time = "\(Int(minutes)):00"
            }
        }
         var initialTime = 0
         var endDate = Date()
        
        // Start the timer with the given amount of minutes
        func start(minutes: Float) {
            self.initialTime = 5
            self.endDate = Date()
            self.isActive = true
            self.endDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: Int(minutes), to: endDate)!
        }
        
        // Reset the timer
        func reset() {
            
            self.minutes = Float(initialTime)
            self.isActive = false
            self.time = "\(Int(minutes)):00"
        }
        
        // Show updates of the timer
        func updateCountdown(){
            guard isActive else { return }
            
            // Gets the current date and makes the time difference calculation
            let now = Date()
            let diff = endDate.timeIntervalSince1970 - now.timeIntervalSince1970
            
            // Checks that the countdown is not <= 0
            if diff <= 0 {
                self.isActive = false
                self.time = "0:00"
                self.showingAlert = true
                return
            }
            
            // Turns the time difference calculation into sensible data and formats it
            let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: diff)
            let calendar = Calendar.current
            let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
            let seconds = calendar.component(.second, from: date)

            // Updates the time string with the formatted time
            self.minutes = Float(minutes)
            self.time = String(format:"%d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
        }
    }
}
```

TimerView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TimerView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm = ViewModel()
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    let width: Double = 250
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Text("Timer: \(vm.time)")
                .font(.system(size: 50, weight: .medium, design: .rounded))
                .alert("Timer done!", isPresented: $vm.showingAlert) {
                    Button("Continue", role: .cancel) {
                        
                    }
                }
                .padding()
            
            HStack(spacing:50) {
                Button("Start") {
                    vm.start(minutes: Float(vm.minutes))
                }
                .padding()
                .background((Color(red: 184/255, green: 243/255, blue: 255/255)))
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .font(Font.system(size: UIFontMetrics.default.scaledValue(for: 16)))
                //.disabled(vm.isActive)
                
                if vm.isActive == true {
                    Button("Pause") {
                        vm.isActive = false
                        //self.timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .background(.red)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .font(Font.system(size: UIFontMetrics.default.scaledValue(for: 16)))
                } else {
                    Button("Resume") {
                        vm.isActive = true
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .background(.green)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .font(Font.system(size: UIFontMetrics.default.scaledValue(for: 16)))
                }
            }
            .frame(width: width)
            }
            .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                vm.updateCountdown()
            }
            
        }
    }


struct TimerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TimerView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed and fixed a number of things in your code:

1. `start()` is being called with the current value of `vm.minutes`, so it is going to start from that value and not `5`.  I changed it to use `self.initialTime` which means it's currently not using the value passed in.  You need to decide if `start()` really wants to take a value and how to use it.
2. `reset()` wasn't being called.  I call it from `start()`.
3. Pause was only pausing the screen update.  I changed it to keep track of the start time of the pause and to compute the amount of time paused so that it could accurately update the displayed time.
4. I made the Pause/Resume button one button with conditional values for title and color based upon `vm.active`.

---

Here is the updated code:

```
extension TimerView {
    final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var isActive = false
        @Published var showingAlert = false
        @Published var time: String = "5:00"
        @Published var minutes: Float = 5.0 {
            didSet {
                self.time = "\(Int(minutes)):00"
            }
        }
        var initialTime = 0
        var endDate = Date()
        var pauseDate = Date()
        var pauseInterval = 0.0
        
        // Start the timer with the given amount of minutes
        func start(minutes: Float) {
            self.initialTime = 5
            self.reset()
            self.endDate = Date()
            self.endDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: self.initialTime, to: endDate)!
            self.isActive = true
        }
        
        // Reset the timer
        func reset() {
            self.isActive = false
            self.pauseInterval = 0.0
            self.minutes = Float(initialTime)
            self.time = "\(Int(minutes)):00"
        }
        
        func pause() {
            if self.isActive {
                pauseDate = Date()
            } else {
                // keep track of the total time we're paused
                pauseInterval += Date().timeIntervalSince(pauseDate)
            }
            self.isActive.toggle()
        }
        
        // Show updates of the timer
        func updateCountdown(){
            guard isActive else { return }
            
            // Gets the current date and makes the time difference calculation
            let now = Date()
            let diff = endDate.timeIntervalSince1970 + self.pauseInterval - now.timeIntervalSince1970
            
            // Checks that the countdown is not <= 0
            if diff <= 0 {
                self.isActive = false
                self.time = "0:00"
                self.showingAlert = true
                return
            }
            
            // Turns the time difference calculation into sensible data and formats it
            let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: diff)
            let calendar = Calendar.current
            let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
            let seconds = calendar.component(.second, from: date)
            
            // Updates the time string with the formatted time
            //self.minutes = Float(minutes)
            self.time = String(format:"%d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
        }
    }
}

struct TimerView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm = ViewModel()
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    let width: Double = 250
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Text("Timer: \(vm.time)")
                .font(.system(size: 50, weight: .medium, design: .rounded))
                .alert("Timer done!", isPresented: $vm.showingAlert) {
                    Button("Continue", role: .cancel) {
                        
                    }
                }
                .padding()
            
            HStack(spacing:50) {
                Button("Start") {
                    vm.start(minutes: Float(vm.minutes))
                }
                .padding()
                .background((Color(red: 184/255, green: 243/255, blue: 255/255)))
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .font(Font.system(size: UIFontMetrics.default.scaledValue(for: 16)))
                //.disabled(vm.isActive)
                
                Button(vm.isActive ? "Pause" : "Resume") {
                    vm.pause()
                    //vm.isActive = false
                    //self.timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
                }
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .background(vm.isActive ? .red : .green)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .font(Font.system(size: UIFontMetrics.default.scaledValue(for: 16)))
                
            }
            .frame(width: width)
        }
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
            vm.updateCountdown()
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I just noticed if you hit Resume after first starting the app, you get a weird result.  This is because the code assumes the timer is paused, but the `endDate` hasn't been set properly yet.  You can fix this by setting `var endDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 5, to: Date())!` or you could disable the Resume button if Start has never been pressed.

Comment: Thanks! You managed to make my code run a lot better but I still noticed that the timer still added an extra 30 minutes when I run it though the countdown time doesn't jump around like crazy anymore

Comment: I'm not seeing the extra 30 minutes with the code I posted.

Comment: ah I see I tried running it on my phone and I'm still seeing the issue. Maybe I can send you a video of the issue?

Comment: Post the video somewhere and put a link here.

Comment: Here's the link to the video: 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1AHY5CMz-h-yM0ZxpRp91vpwpKOHZj_vI

Comment: Please make the access public.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. Its public now.

Comment: Create a new project and use the code I posted.  Can you reproduce the problem with that code?  If not, then there is something different about your code.